# Method for parsing floats and adding totals

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, parsing

My intention is to create a nice DRY method (`add`) which will take care of parsing floats and adding totals internally and will be called by other methods.

I feel like I'm jumping through unnecessary complex hoops here. Can anyone help me out?

PS: the intention is to be able to specify different objects with add, so if I had a label object called 'food' with a credit property I could create a function called `addFoodCredit(amount)` which would call `add( amount, 'credit', 'labels', 'food')`.

The full code can be seen [here](http://codepen.io/liam-ryan/pen/GgOpvK?editors=001).

```
var dateObject = function() {
    var totals = {
        totalDebit: 0,
        totalCredit: 0,
        labels: {}
   }

    var add = function add( amount ) {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments) 
        var objectReference = totals;
        var floatAmount = parseFloat (args.shift());
        var objectKey = args.shift();
        while(args.length > 0) {
          objectReference = objectReference[args.shift()];
        }
        var currentTotal = parseFloat( objectReference[objectKey] );
        objectReference[objectKey] = currentTotal + floatAmount;
        console.log(objectReference, objectKey);
        console.log(totals.totalDebit)
    };

    this.addCredit = function addCredit( amount ) {
        add( amount, 'totalCredit' );
    };

    this.addDebit = function addDebit ( amount ) {
        add( amount, 'totalDebit');
    };

    this.addLabel = function ( label, amount, type ) {
        var labelName = label + '-' + type;
        if ( ! totals.labels.labelName ) {
            totals.labels[labelName] = 0;
        }

        add(amount, labelName, 'labels')
    }

  this.print = function() {console.log(totals)};

};

var x = new dateObject();
x.addCredit(15);
x.addCredit(21);
x.addDebit(12.42);
x.addDebit(122);
x.addLabel('food', 20, 'dr')
x.print();
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. By reading your question I'm not sure if your code works. Do know that your code need to work for your question to be on-topic on Code Review. See [help] for more information.

Comment: Thanks Marc-Andre, it is working in the pen I have edited to copy the code over in its entirety, I wanted to focus on the add method in the question

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I hope you get some good reviews!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `add` method is overly complex for no real benefit. It is hitting a thumbtack with a sledge hammer. The `add` method is used for waaaay to much. It's not clear what it does. I had to spend 5 minutes dissecting what it did. For an 11 line method, that's pretty long.

I understand you are trying to DRY up your code, but you have sacrificed clarity for perceived duplication of code. Adding to the credit and debit totals *appears* to be duplicated code, when actually it is not. You are better off removing the `add` method and going for something explicit. What you *do* want to DRY up is the conversions of `amount` values to numbers, and perhaps some error checking.

Defining this inside your `dateObject` class makes ensuring arguments are numbers a quick one-liner.

```
var toNumber = function(x) {
    var n = Number(x);

    if (isNaN(n)) {
        throw new Error("Invalid number: " + amount);
    }

    return n;
};
```

Now, your `addCredit` and `addDebit` methods become explicit and easy to read:

```
this.addCredit = function(amount) {
    totals.totalCredit += toNumber(amount);
};

this.addDebit = function(amount) {
    totals.totalDebit += toNumber(amount);
};
```

The `addLabel` method flat out confused me for a good while because it delegated to the `add` method. As a general rule, avoid turning methods into a "utility belt" where they perform more than one task. It makes for confusing code that is hard to maintain and debug.

The `addLabel` method (as far as I can tell) becomes much easier to visualize and debug as well:

```
this.addLabel = function(label, amount, type) {
    var key = label + "-" + type;
    totals.labels[key] = totals.labels[key] || 0;
    total.labels[key] += toNumber(amount);
};
```

And now on to every programmers' favorite subject: naming things :)

You have a "class" called `dateObject`. Naming conventions in JavaScript dictate that "classes", or more accurately constructor functions, should capitalize their first letter. Secondly, your `dateObject` class does nothing at all with dates, and is confusing because JavaScript has a `Date` class. Crediting and debiting amounts has nothing to do with dates. I realize you omitted some code but consider renaming this class to something like `Account`:

```
function Account() {
    var totals = {
        totalDebit: 0,
        totalCredit: 0,
        labels: {}
    };

    var toNumber = function(x) {
        var n = Number(x);

        if (isNaN(n)) {
            throw new Error("Invalid number: " + amount);
        }

        return n;
    };

    this.addCredit = function(amount) {
        totals.totalCredit += toNumber(amount);
    };

    this.addDebit = function(amount) {
        totals.totalDebit += toNumber(amount);
    };

    this.addLabel = function(label, amount, type) {
        var key = label + "-" + type;
        totals.labels[key] = totals.labels[key] || 0;
        total.labels[key] += toNumber(amount);
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear feedback and effort put into this answer, it's really appreciated!